# need help in writing in xsd for xml?

Tags: xml, xsd

need xsd for the following xml

```
<Author Title="Mr." BirthYear="1882">
Lalchand
</Author>
```

i wrote like this

```
<xs:element name="Author">
<xs:complexType>
     <xs:attribute name="Title" type="xs:string"/>
     <xs:attribute name="BirthYear" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

need help in writing the value of Author that is Lalchand

Answer (score 0):

If you use visual studio, you can open your XML file in visual studio and Select `XML` -> `Create Schema` option in the main menu while you're in edit-mode of your XML file.

additionally, you can use **[xsd.exe tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.80).aspx)** generate xsd from your XML.

> The XML Schema Definition (Xsd.exe)
>   tool generates XML schema or common
>   language runtime classes from XDR,
>   XML, and XSD files, or from classes in
>   a runtime assembly.